# Insert record from one table into another when record is selected on asp.net Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using C# ASP.net, and relative new to it, and trying to accomplish below.

In VS2010 web application project, I have a webform with a Gridview which reads data off table1 of SQL server 2008. The Gridview has select option.

Requirement is, when I select a row on gridview, it inserts the selected row into table2.
Both tables are in same db with same data types.

Thanks in advance

P.S. I rephrased same question and deleted old post. Hope it is clear this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
I grabbed the selectedidexchange event
Created new GridViewRow instance
Created new connection to table2 and SQLcommand to write into table2
With command I added sqlparameters with values equal to row and its column value through GridViewRow instance
opened connection
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();